# Best practices of exporting records from HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm using [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) as the view. I have a table of records and there are 3 scenarios of export:

1. Export all from all pages
2. Export only selected by a checkbox
3. Export only filtered records

I'm a bit confusing of how can I implement these scenarios...
Here are my assumptions and doubts:

1. Export all - just use `$('#table tr')`. Yeah, it will really export all
2. Export only selected - use again `$('#table tr')` and for each item check if it the checkbox is enabled
3. Filtered records. And there I'm confusing. I can use `$('#table tr:visible')`, but what if I have 12 filtered records, but only 10 records are on the page and another 2 are on another page?

Are there some best-practices of how to derermine which records should be exported (into csv/xls) for these 3 cases?

Comment: Surely you would have the pagination problem in all scenarios though? Is the data strictly HTML only or is there an API call made, with JSON / XML data?

Comment: All the data in the HTML. To make API calls for exporting is another question, and I would like not to do it now.

Comment: You do have an API - http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#api - you should look to use this to get the data

Comment: You shouldn't be using jQuery for this task - look at the tablesorter API.

Comment: Is the data user provided or provided by the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [output widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html) has a [`output_savedRows` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html#output_saverows) which has the following settings:

- `"filtered"` which outputs rows that match the filter query. It does this by using the following selector:

  ```
  $('tr').not('.filtered')
  ```

  a class added by the [`filter_filteredRow` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#widget-filter-filteredrow)
- `"visible"` which only outputs visible rows. Rows hidden by the pager, filter or set to `display: none` will not be included in the output. The visible selector is used in this case:

  ```
  $('tr:visible')
  ```
- `"all"` will output all rows. This includes hidden & filtered rows.

  ```
  $('tr')
  ```

---

- I plan to add a new setting `"selected"` in v2.22.2, which will use a new option `output_selected` that includes a row class name that the output widget uses to include in the output.

  ```
  $('tr.selected')
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I figured this out by myself, and your answer just confirms my thoughts)

Comment: I actually ended up not adding "selected" as a setting. Instead the `output_saveRows` option will now accept a jQuery selector - see [this comment](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/923#issuecomment-109819330) for more details.